# What is use of specifying x coordinates for bar graphs in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

This example for bar charts is taken from **Data Science From Scratch by Joel Grus**

```
movies = ["Annie Hall", "Ben-Hur", "Casablanca", "Gandhi", "West Side Story"]
num_oscars = [5, 11, 3, 8, 10]

# plot bars with left x-coordinates [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], heights [num_oscars]
plt.bar(range(len(movies)), num_oscars)

plt.title("My Favorite Movies")     # add a title
plt.ylabel("# of Academy Awards")   # label the y-axis

# label x-axis with movie names at bar centers
plt.xticks(range(len(movies)), movies)

plt.show()
```

My issue is what `plt.bar()` call. Why is it even necessary to specify the left x coordinates for the bar graph? Why not just supply the height of the bars?

**I mean why not just specify the heights of the individual bars, why is the left coordinate even needed ?** **Isn't it just sufficient to specify the height?** For those bars which have a height of 0, you can just specify 0 in the height iterable that is supplied.

Why specify the left x coordinates? What purpose does that serve? What does the x coordinates even do?

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) offers in no reason as to why this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x coordinate doesn't need to be an integer; it can be a list of names. The expected use in the later releases (since 2.1) is this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

movies = ["Annie Hall", "Ben-Hur", "Casablanca", "Gandhi", "West Side Story"]
num_oscars = [5, 11, 3, 8, 10]

plt.bar(movies, num_oscars)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I suspect the source of the code in the OP is older than the possibility to use strings as x data (which got introduced into matplotlib in version 2.1).

Comment: True - clarified answer.

Comment: @solidpixel So in the older releases there was actually no real use for the x-coordinates? I mean in my example I am assigning xticks.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to be able to swap chart type without completely restructuring the code, so being able to swap chart type just by changing function, but keeping most of the parameter signature the same is a "use" even if not a direct one.

Comment: ... but I'm hypothesizing here - I'm not involved in maintaining it ...

Answer (score 2):

There are two components of this question. The first,

#### 1. What is the use of `x` in `plt.bar(x,y)`?

- **A. numeric bar plot**

  ```
  x = [3,5,6,9]
  y = [2,3,4,2]
  plt.bar(x,y)
  ```

  [image]
- **B. Custom positions, e.g. grouped bars**

  ```
  x = np.arange(5)
  y1 = np.array([2,3,4,2,3])
  y2 = np.array([3,4,3,3,2])
  plt.bar(x-0.2,y1, width=0.4)
  plt.bar(x+0.2,y2, width=0.4)
  ```

  [image]

#### 2. Why not allow for `plt.bar(y)`?

Given that many bar plots are categorical in nature, one might ask why `plt.bar(y)` would not fall back to `plt.bar(range(len(y)), y)` if no `x` is provided. This is backed by the fact that `plt.plot(y)` actually does exactly that.

Well, first the obvious "...because no one has implemented it."; this is a pretty common reason in open-source projects which are mainly developped by volunteers in their free time. But then, also, the experience with the plot function taking a variable amount of arguments has been a major source of confusion and a true maintainance burden in the past. Supporting only a clear and obvious signature is much easier and less confusing, even if it means that in certain cases obvious information (like the first n integers) need to be provided as argument.

Comment: Can you please explain why did you do `x+0.2` ?? What does that acheive?

Comment: `0.2` is half the width of a bar. We shift the blue bars by half the width to the left and the orange bars by half the width to the right, such that they don't overlap.

Comment: Is that measurement in percent or pixels? What is the unit of calculation? How is the calculation done?

Comment: Neither, nor. It's data units, just as everything else in an axes.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation,

```
x : sequence of scalars
The x coordinates of the bars. See also align for the alignment of the bars to the coordinates.
```

x is mandatory for the plot. It's a set of co-ordinates to represent the bar graph. However it can be anything, but the total number of entries in x and height should match.